# setfetchsize in datastax java : when fetchSize == rowcount then it fails with exception DriverInternalError

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, datastax

The versions I used is : `datastax java driver 2.0.1 & 2.0.2`

```
cassandra version : [cqlsh 4.1.0 | Cassandra 2.0.4 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
```

code part:

```
    Statement stmt = new SimpleStatement("SELECT id FROM accounts;"); 
    stmt.setFetchSize(5); 
    session.execute(stmt); 
    for (Row r:result.all()){
        System.out.println(r.toString());
    }
```

or

```
   for (Row r:result){
        System.out.println(r.toString());
    }
```

exception happens at

`for (Row r:result)`

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverInternalError: An unexpected error occurred server side on /122.248.212.139:9042: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal Capacity: -1
at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverInternalError.copy(DriverInternalError.java:42)
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:256)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedResultSet$MultiPage.prepareNextRow(ArrayBackedResultSet.java:259)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedResultSet$MultiPage.isExhausted(ArrayBackedResultSet.java:222)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedResultSet$1.hasNext(ArrayBackedResultSet.java:115)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedResultSet.all(ArrayBackedResultSet.java:104)
at com.minjar.simplifyit.cost.data.cassandra.DataStaxCassandraHandler.main(DataStaxCassandraHandler.java:407)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverInternalError: An unexpected error occurred server side on /122.248.212.139:9042: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal Capacity: -1
at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:86)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedResultSet$MultiPage$1.onSet(ArrayBackedResultSet.java:329)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:235)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.onSet(RequestHandler.java:367)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.messageReceived(Connection.java:571)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:70)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem with Cassandra 2.0.4, but not with 2.0.5. My guess is that you're running into [CASSANDRA-6555](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6555).

I suggest upgrading your cluster to the latest stable version, 2.0.8.

Comment: thanks, upgrading cluster to the latest stable version helped.